# .bbl file forming in the wrong folder

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib, chapters, thesis

I am writing my thesis by TeXstudio and the different chapter are organized in subfolder which I `\include` in the main file.

To organize the bibliography I am using `natbib` and create a bibliography at the end of each chapter.

Unfortunately, the `.bbl` file is generated in the main folder instead of the chapter subfolders. This drive TeXstudio to not find the `.bbl` file and block the formation of the bibliography after each chapter.

To be clear I can find the file `thesis.bbl` (empty), but not the file `chapter 2.bbl`. I am starting from a `chapter 2.bib` file in the subfolder.

How can I force latex to generate the `.bbl` file for each chapter?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use a package like chapterbib?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have both natbib and chapterbib, but the .bbl file keeps on spawing out of the main folder instead of the chapter subfolder. Of course, when compiling the code looks for the .bbl file in the subfolder

Comment: well without more exact info about your code and structure and how you call bibtex it is difficult to say. Make in a test folder a small example without any subfolders and only one \include and test if that works.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a newbie to LateX so I don't really know which kind of information you need about the code. 

I have edited the main question with the organization of the chapters from my file. 

I use \include to{chapter 1/chapter 1.tex} to insert the different chapter files.

Comment: well as newbie you shouldn't directly create complicated structures. As I wrote: start with a small test example without subfolders in a test folder.

Comment: Sure! I already tried a first document without subfolders. Nothing came up and I was feeling quite confident. The problem rose up when multiple folders joined the project.

Comment: well then add one subfolder with a small example. This is something people can try. And better avoid spaces in file and folder names, they can easily lead to errors.